# python - Error while opening XLS file with xlrd after creating the same file with xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd, xlwt

My script creates XLS file (with some data populated in it) using xlwt module and saves it in working directory. This first part of the operation is done successfully. In the same script, next part is to read the saved XLS file and based on that file, create another XLS file populated with some values. Once first XLS is saved I get an error to read that saved XLS using xlrd as under;

```
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR:   File "C:\Esri_SCRIPTS\GDB_FC_SourceMapping_Service_V6\GDB_FC_SourceMapping_V6_Dev.py", line 200, in <module>
ERROR:     wb=xlrd.open_workbook(CurWrokDir + '\DataSources.xls')
ERROR:   File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 454, in open_workbook
ERROR:     bk.parse_globals()
ERROR:   File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1473, in parse_globals
ERROR:     self.handle_sst(data)
ERROR:   File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1446, in handle_sst
ERROR:     self._sharedstrings = unpack_SST_table(strlist, uniquestrings)
ERROR:   File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1663, in unpack_SST_table
ERROR:     nchars = local_unpack('<H', data[pos:pos+2])[0]
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2
ERROR:
ERROR: unpack requires a string argument of length 2
```

The work around I found by searching on this forum is to open the XLS output saved from first part, SAVE it and close it. Run the second part of the script and it will run successfully.

What I want to achieve is to run the script all together without any error. In other words, run the script...first part will save the XLS and immediately second part will start reading the save XLS output from first part and generate second output as XLS.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi guys, I am not sure if this is the correct location for posting this python issue, but anyone to help me with this issue?

Comment: There isn't enough information provided here to help you debug this. You should provide small, complete examples of the `xlwt` and `xlrd` programs that you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share the code developed for my organization, but I can give more descriptive details if that suffice the need.

Comment: I am creating an XLS1.xls at location "a" (for example) with xlwt module. I am adding a sheet to this XLS1.xls and saving it with the name of the geodatabase (e.g. GDB1@GDB.gdb --> sheet name within the XLS1.xls) which I am scanning (i.e. processing data within the geodatabase) using my script. I am populating some values (in multiple rows and columns) in XLS1 by scanning geodatabases, map documents and published services. This XLS1 at location "a" is saved at the end by "MyWorkbook.save(CurWrokDir + 'XLS1').

Comment: Once this XLS1.xls with sheet (with name of geodatabase as mentioned above) is created, my second part of the script tries to read the same XLS1.xls at location "a" using xlrd and thats where I get this error.

Comment: As a workoround, I open XLS1.xls, save it (without making any changes to it) and close it. Then I run second part of my script seperately, it runs fine and creates another XLS2.xls from XLS1.xls. When I try to run part one and part two altogether, it gives above error when it starts second part of the script to read XSL1.xls......Hope this helps (apology that I am not able to provide any code)...thanks for the help...

Comment: You don't need to show "the code developed for your organization". A sample program that demonstrates the issue would do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fundamental issue with writing a file via `xlwt` and re-reading it via `xlrd` as shown in this example:

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

# Write an Excel file.
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')

worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello')
worksheet.write(1, 0, 12345)

workbook.save('test.xls')

# Now read it back in.
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

print worksheet.row(0)[0].value
print worksheet.row(1)[0].value
```

Prints:

```
$ python reread.py
Hello
12345.0
```

So it is up to you to debug what is the issue in your program that is causing the error.

Given that you don't see the issue after you save the file in Excel it may well be that this is some issue in `xlwt` but again you need to demonstrate that or provide some way for the developers to debug it.